# systemd command fails /bin/bash not found

Tags: ubuntu, ruby, systemd

Currently trying to get a new systemd script to work. The script has the following included:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'bundle exec sidekiq -e production'
```

However that seems not to work.

The error I then get is:

```
Failed at step CHDIR spawning /bin/bash: No such file or directory
```

I need to execute the command as a login shell.

Comment: Why are you even calling bash at all? Just call the program you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirm where bash is located on your system using

```
 which bash
```

Then update your ExecStart line accordingly.

Comment: That fixed it thanks. Plus I had my WorkingDirectory setup wrong.

Comment: That's strange, though: On my Ubuntu 16.04, bash *is* at /bin/bash.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that specified `WorkingDirectory` didn't exist. When I created directory the problem has gone

Comment: Correct. This is the right answer. The real issue is because of WorkingDirectory.